# Generic std::function to store a generic lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, std-function, generic-lambda

When generic lambda is stored as a `std::function`, we need to provide a concrete type, something like,

```
std::function<double(double)>
```

thus binding to a specific type,

The following declaration:

```
std::function<auto(auto)>
```

throws a compiler error.

I understand that, from c++14 onwards, `auto` can be used to store return value of a lambda, but is there a way to achieve this when storing a lambda in `std::function`?

Comment: This `std::function` should be callable somehow. (It overloads `operator()`.) How do you intend to do it if the signature is unknown?

Comment: Even if you can store such functors, you can't use them anyway. If one needs two string parms and one needs only an int, how you call them? What kind of software design you have in mind? It looks you have a general design problem, not a problem to store something ;)

Comment: you can't do it with a std::function, you can do it with a template<class T> and store T in your class, then you can construct your class with a generic lambda [](auto arg) {/* return something*/};

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Not even with a custom wrote `std::function`. This is a fundamental limit of type erasure.

Intuitively, templates requires the type information available at the point of function call but type erasure in `std::function` destroys that information.

On a more detailed level, type erasure works by storing the set of operations in a type-agnostic way at compile-time, either implicitly by virtual functions or explicitly by function pointers. Templates are effectively an infinite family of operations and is thus impossible to be stored.

If you know the fixed set of function signatures you will be using, you can write a custom `std::function`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Generic lambda and `std::function` are completely different things.

You can rougly see an `auto(auto)` lambda as a not-template class with a template `operator()`.

Something as

```
struct myUnnamedLambdaStruct
 {
   // ...

   template <typename T>
   auto operator() (T t) const 
    { /* .... */ };
 };
```

Where `std::function()` is the contrary: it's a (specialization of a) template class with a not-template `operator()`

```
template <typename>
class function;

template <typename RetType, typename ... ArgTypes>
class function<RetType(ArgTypes...)>
 {
   // a lot of other members/methods

   public:
      RetType operator() (ArgTypes ... args) const
       { /* .... */ }
 };
```

So a generic lambda object doesn't contain a single `operator()` but a set of `operator()` where a `std::function` object contain a single `operator()`.

You can "save" a generic lambda in a `std::function` but only fixing, one time for all, the `RetType` and the `ArgTypes...`. That is: selecting a single `operator()`, in the available set of `operator()`s, and forgetting all the others.